# Iterate to get the list of the lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a Data Frame `line`:

```
data = [[10, 10, 10,10,10,10,10,10], [10, 10, 10,10,10,10,10,10], [10, 10, 10,10,10,10,10,10]]
line = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['0', '0.1','1', '1.1','2', '2.1','3', '3.1']) 
line
```

---

What I did so far:

```
border_1 = line[['2','2.1']]
border_1 = border_1.rename(columns={'2': 'longitude', '2.1': 'latitude'})
border_1 = border_1.dropna()
```

I did it with `[['2','2.1']]`. Now I want to do it with every couple starting with 0 0.1 1 1.1 and so on to get `border_1`

---

How apply to the whole data frame?

---

```
cols = line.columns.tolist()
for i in range(0, len(cols), 2):
    border_1 = line[cols[i], cols[i+1]]
    border_1 = border_1.rename(columns={cols[i]: 'longitude', cols[i+i]: 'latitude'})
    border_1 = border_1.dropna()
```

---

```
KeyError: ('0', '0.1')
```

Comment: Please add an example of your DataFrame that can be copied into a text editor

Comment: What do you mean by length of every column?

Comment: @DanielMesejo number of rows, number of points

Comment: Its a dataframe, each col must have the same amount of rows

Comment: COuld you add the expected output for the sample you just created

Comment: @DanielMesejo DOne. Check my sample code

Comment: seems like you can `groupby` along `axis=1` using `df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]` as your grouper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two syntactic errors:

First, to get multiple columns you need to use them as a list:

```py
for i in range(0, len(cols), 2):
    border_1 = line[[cols[i], cols[i+1]]]
```

Second, a simple typo, but `cols[i+i]` gets out of range quickly.

```py
    border_1 = border_1.rename(columns={cols[i]: 'longitude', cols[i+1]: 'latitude'})
```

Comment: Seems nice, but desired output is to get the data frame or list like: for columns `0 and 0.1` `len is 45`, then for  `1 and 1.1` `len is 23`,  `2 and 2.1` `len is 33`and so on

Comment: I solved the error you mentioned at the end of your post. I assume you can use the loop to get what you need for each pair of x and x.1 values, otherwise I don't understand your post or question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Build a New DataFrame with a MultiIndex

```
cols = (
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        tuple(map(int, (x +  '.0').split('.')[:2]))
        for x in line.columns
    ]).set_levels(['longitude', 'latitude'], level=1)
)

border = pd.DataFrame({c: v for c, (k, v) in zip(cols, line.iteritems())})
border

          0                  1                  2                  3         
  longitude latitude longitude latitude longitude latitude longitude latitude
0        10       10        10       10        10       10        10       10
1        10       10        10       10        10       10        10       10
2        10       10        10       10        10       10        10       10
```